# Tomcat session.ser

Tags: java, oracle11g, tomcat6, oracle-adf, oracleapplications

im using apache-tomcat6.0.24..and Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 to install my EGRCM application.when im restarting my tomcat it will araise some exceptions..the problem is when redeploy my appplication it could not open..please help me find out the problem.

thanks in advance.

The problem will be shown below

on.StandardManager doUnload
SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/grc/grcapp/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/grc/SESSIONS.ser (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/grc/grcapp/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/grc/SESSIONS.ser (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

2012-12-03 04:50:38,180 ERROR [main] JuliToLog4jHandler:76 (org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager:669) Dec 3, 2012 4:50:38 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stop
SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/grc/grcapp/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/grc/SESSIONS.ser (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:643)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

2012-12-03 04:50:38,182 INFO  [main] QuartzScheduler:186 Stopping scheduler
2012-12-03 04:50:38,182 INFO  [main] QuartzScheduler:570 Scheduler AGScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2012-12-03 04:50:38,183 INFO  [main] QuartzScheduler:496 Scheduler AGScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.

2012-12-03 04:56:47,756 ERROR [main] JuliToLog4jHandler:76 (oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack:83) Dec 3, 2012 4:56:47 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: Failed to register config mbean for defaultApplicationName.

2012-12-03 04:56:47,757 ERROR [main] JuliToLog4jHandler:76 (oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack:84) Dec 3, 2012 4:56:47 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE:
oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
        at oracle.jrf.ServerPlatformSupportFactory.getInstance(ServerPlatformSupportFactory.java:79)
        at oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomcat is attempting to save all the session stored objects(which are serializable) as a file called sessions.ser when tomcat shuts down, so that it can bring that session back during startup.

During start it will attempt to read sessions.ser file to restore session.
Your problem seems to a permission issue. Try granting read/write privileges to folder 
 /home/grc/grcapp/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/grc

using chmod

Comment: Thanks for your answer subin..but actually im working in root directory and it has read/write privileges also i have raised SR there is no issues in granting privileges. what can i do now?