# SSL Certificate installation issue on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am trying to install Internet SSL certificate in our TOMCAT server which is in Unix server.

Here are the steps I did

1 . Created the keystore
2.  Created the CSR
3. Received the new SSL Certificate
4. Installed the certificate
5. Changed the server.xml  for the new certificate
6. Restated the web server, and now I am having some errors,

Pls let me know if you have any idea.

```
                    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
    SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/_/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/_/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stop
    SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/_/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:5.
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
    SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/archive_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/archive_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stop
    SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/archive_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
    SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/static_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/static_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stop
    SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mars/web/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/work/Catalina/localhost/static_reports/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied (errno:13))
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:489)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:667)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4362)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1245)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1216)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1055)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1067)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:510)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
    WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:519)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:577)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol destroy
    INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-80
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
    SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:01 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
    SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N:/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server:/opt/java6/jre/../lib/IA64N:/usr/lib:/mars/web/siteminder/webagent/bin:/usr/lib:/mars/web/siteminder/webagent/bin:/lib:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib32:/usr/lib
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:05 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
    SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
    java.net.BindException: Permission denied (errno:13):80
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.initEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:298)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol.init(Http11BaseProtocol.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1002)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:578)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:782)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:504)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:267)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
    Nov 6, 2015 11:23:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load


    INFO: Server startup in 5055 ms
```

Update:

I shutdown the TOMCAT, removed the work directory where Session.ser belongs and restarted the server. Found these errors now. Any help please

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1068)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
    Nov 11, 2015 5:30:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Tomcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat session.ser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718077/tomcat-session-ser)

Comment: I shutdown the TOMCAT, removed the work directory where Session.ser belongs and restarted the server.

Comment: I shutdown the TOMCAT, removed the work directory where Session.ser belongs and restarted the server. Found these errors now   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. While importing the certificates, I accidentally deleted the private key. I had to replace the certificate. I followed the same steps with the new certificate. It worked fine.